# Multiple errors grunt serve

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, npm, bower

I was trying to start the server for the angular-gantt demo, everything works, I installed all the dependences required with `npm install` and `grunt install` also the `grunt test` works and it compiles executing `grunt`, but when I try to run the demo application using `grunt serve` I have a lot of errors.

Here is the output of the terminal

```
eri-174-235:angular-gantt jnd0$ grunt serve

Loading "release-it.js" tasks...ERROR

>> Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/jnd0/.config/configstore/insight-release-it.json'
>> You don't have access to this file.

Warning: Task "serve" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this github thread: https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman.github.io/issues/282

On linux you will need to add permissions `chmod g+rwx` to that file, You may try it on OS X - it should work too.

Full command:

```
chmod g+rwx /Users/jnd0/ /Users/jnd0/.config /Users/jnd0/.config/configstore
```